# js fill input fields

Tags: javascript, events

I have a form with inputs, and I try to fill it's with javascript and submit the form

Here http://avito.ru/additem

Enter email, use code

```
   var e=document.querySelectorAll("[data-write-id=email]")[0];
   e.value="mail@imail.com";
```

In form that appear at next step use code

```
 e=document.querySelectorAll("[data-write-id=name]")[0];
 e.value="Mynameis";
 e=document.querySelectorAll("[data-write-id=phone]")[0];
 e.value="89999799991";
 e=document.getElementsByClassName("js-captcha-input")[0];
 e.value="s97jv"; e=document.getElementsByClassName("js-submit")[1];
 e.click;
```

**And get errors when submit**

> enter your name
>
> enter your phone
>
> enter chapcha (that is not problem I know that capcha is wrong and it need to chage it value each time)

I also try to use for each input the code to initialize functions that happens when user type letter but not work

```
  e.setfocus;
  e.click;
  e.change;
  e.mouseout;
  e.mouseenter;
  e.mouseleave;
  e.mousehover;
  e.mousedown;
  e.mouseup;
  e.mouseover;
  e.mousemove;
  e.onblur;
  e.oninput;
  e.keypress;
  e.keydown;
  e.keyup;
  e.focusout;
```

**In inspector I see that name and phone is empty send**

> Remote Address:225.79.82.192:443
>
> Request Method:POST
>
> Status Code:200 OK
>
> Request Headers
>
> Provisional headers are shown
>
> Accept:*/*
>
> Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
>
> X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
>
> Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
>
> source:add
>
> captcha:s97jv
>
> email:mail@mail.com
>
> private:1
>
> phone:
>
> name:
>
> Response Headers

That code show message that input not filled "Заполните поле" translate "please enter text"

```
    t.prototype.checkFields = function () {
      var e = this,
      t = this.$container.find('.form-fieldset'),
      a = 0;
      return t.filter(':visible').each(function (t, i) {
        var s = $(i),
        n = s.find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"]'),
        r = n.data('write-id');
        - 1 === e.settings.emptyIgnoring.indexOf(r) && n.length && !n.prop('disabled') && (n.val().trim() || (a++, s.addClass('is-js-error').find('.form-fieldset__error').html('Заполните поле'))) /*Заполните поле translate please enter text*/
      }),
      a
  },
```

Comment: can you share a fiddle of what you have tried?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("[data-name=name]")[0]; Is the same as document.querySelector("[data-name=name]"); but please show the HTML and the relevant validation that alerts the error. Why are you just stating the event handlers? e.mouseup; does not do anything

Comment: Show your code AND html. All this does nothing for you `e.setfocus;
 e.click;
 e.change;
 e.mouseout;
 e.mouseenter;
 e.mouseleave;
 e.mousehover;
 e.mousedown;
 e.mouseup;
 e.mouseover;
 e.mousemove;
 e.onblur;

 e.oninput;
 e.keypress;
 e.keydown;
 e.keyup;
 e.focusout;` - we have currently no idea what you mean by "(ajax return warning)" Perhaps your server code is wrong